# asp.net loading page based on previous link

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with few images. Also have a page where content based on drop down link is pulled from db. I currently have this code for !ispostback

```
private void FillPage()
    {
        ArrayList categoryList = new ArrayList();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            categoryList = ConnectionClass.GetMenuByCategory("Appetizer");
        }
        else
        {
            categoryList = ConnectionClass.GetMenuByCategory(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        }
```

is is possible based on what img is clicked to change the inital getmenubycategory from appetizer to what ever img is selected. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with query strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void FillPage()
    {
        ArrayList categoryList = new ArrayList();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             if (Request.QueryString["category"] != null) 
             {
                 string categoryName = Request.QueryString["category"] as string;

                 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryName)
                 {
                     switch(categoryName)
                     {
                         case "Entree":
                             categoryList = ConnectionClass.GetMenuByCategory("Entree");
                             break;
                         case "Dessert":
                             categoryList = ConnectionClass.GetMenuByCategory("Dessert");
                             break;
                         default:
                             categoryList = ConnectionClass.GetMenuByCategory("Appetizer");
                             break;
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
        else
        {
             categoryList = ConnectionClass.GetMenuByCategory(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        }
```

Comment: I have attached the following code to the previous page along with changing the script to the script above. However when clicked it does not produce the results. It shows the page with no data. here is the code         <a href="items.aspx?category=Rolls" class="image"><img src="../img/menu/newimg/app.gif"/></a>
        <a href="items.aspx?category=Grilled" class="image"><img src="../img/menu/newimg/grill.gif" /> </a>

Comment: also the above code !IsNullorEmpty produces the error: Error 25 The name 'IsNullOrEmpty' does not exist in the current context. I changed it to string.IsNullorEmpty(categoryName)

Comment: Sorry forgot that IsNullOrEmpty is part of the String class, see edited code.

Comment: Have you debugged to see if your category query string value is actually getting to the FillPage method?

Comment: thanks the string class was holding it up. New to all of this so after research and your help i got it corrected works great. thanks.

Comment: Great, glad it worked out. Good luck with your journey into .NET! LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET method:

```
 <a href="go.aspx?img=1"><img src="img1.jpg/></a>
 <a href="go.aspx?img=2"><img src="img2.jpg/></a>
```

and in code behind:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["img"]))
    if(Request.QueryString["img"]=="1")
        //some initializing
    else
        //another initializing
```